# react native pagos in-app

Tags: android, reactjs

Tengo bastantes dudas sobre los pagos dentro de la aplicación.
Google nos rechazó nuestra app, por que dice que tenemos que implementar los pagos dentro de la app

Mi problema viene es que todo lo que me encuentro se refiere a suscripción... y nuestro modelo no es de suscripción.
Nuestro producto son clases online por videoconferencia.
El usuario paga una vez, hace su clase y ya... Si quiere otra vuelve a pagar.
A ver si alguien me puede ayudar en entender mejor esto.
Revenuecat vendría bien?

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigas, es importante para obtener buenas respuestas, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Que opciones le diste como identificaste tu app? Y cual es el mensaje de google sobre eso de que necesitas implementar pago.

Answer (score 0):

RevenueCat es un servicio que te facilita la integración con las tiendas (Apple store y Google Play). La facilidad es que te centras en el desarrollo de tu aplicación dejando que sea Revenue quien te ayuda este proceso. Digo te ayuda porque tampoco es que no tengas que picar código, pero te facilita con el mismo código la integración en ambas tiendas.

Yo estoy desarrollando en flutter el mismo modelo que el que indicas (pagas una vez y ya está) utilizando Revenue. Hay algún otro por ahí que hace lo mismo (https://glassfy.io/) pero aún no lo he probado.

Saludos,